# How to search or find data from multiple collection in mongoose using Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I am building the MERN app of Movies, where I have to implement search field, but stuck at how I can run search or query through multiple collections in MongoDB and get the data based on search in NodeJS.

controllers/movies.js

```
        import MoviePost from "../../models/movies/moviesSchema.js";
        import mongoose from 'mongoose'

        export const getAllMov=async(req,res)=>{
            try {
                const data=await MoviePost.find().sort({_id:-1})
                res.status(201).json(data)
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(401).json('error')
            }
        }

        export const getMovById=async(req,res)=>{
            const {id} =req.params
            try {
                const data=await MoviePost.findById(id)
                res.status(201).json(data)
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(401).json('error')
            }
        }

        export const getMov=async(req,res)=>{
            const limit=10
            const page=1
            try {
                const data=await MoviePost.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(limit * 1).skip((page-1)*limit)
                res.status(201).json(data)
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(401).json('error')
            }
        }

        export const createMov=async(req,res)=>{
            const data=req.body
            const movie=new MoviePost(data)
            try {
                await movie.save()
                res.status(201).json(movie)
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(401).json('error')
            }
        }

        export const updateMov=async(req,res)=>{
            const {id}=req.params
            const updateMovie=req.body
            if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid((id))) return res.status(401).json('no data with that id')
            const updatedMovie=await MoviePost.findByIdAndUpdate(id,updateMovie,{new:true})
            res.status(201).json(updatedMovie)
        }

        export const deleteMov=async(req,res)=>{
            const {id}=req.params
            if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid((id))) return res.status(401).json('no data with that id')
            await MoviePost.findByIdAndRemove(id)
            res.status(201).json('data Deleted')
        }

        export const getDataBySearch=async(req,res)=>{
            const {searchQuery}=req.query
            try {
                const title=new RegExp(searchQuery,'i')
                const data=await MoviePost.find({title})
                res.status(201).json(data)
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(404).json({message:error.message})
            }
        }
```

in models there are three mongoose model with same schema, models named as in codes:

1. Movies
2. Trending
3. Webshow

I am putting movies.js here same applies for all models

models/movies.js

```
            import mongoose from 'mongoose'

            const MovieSchema=mongoose.Schema({
                poster:String,
                youtube:String,
                title:String,
                genre:[String],
                director:String,
                duration:String,
                quality:String,
                release:String,
                imdb:String,
                name:String,
                description:String,
                detailtitle:String,
                screenshots:[String],
                createdAt:{
                    type:Date,
                    default:new Date()
                }
            })

            var WebShowPost=mongoose.model('Webshow',MovieSchema)

            export default WebShowPost
```

as for the models routes are all similar.

routes/movies.js

```
            import express from 'express'
            const router=express.Router()
            import { createMov, deleteMov, getAllMov, getMov, getMovById, updateMov,getDataBySearch } from '../../controllers/movies/movies.js'

            router.get('/search',getDataBySearch)
            router.get('/',getMov)
            router.get('/all',getAllMov)
            router.get('/:id',getMovById)
            router.post('/',createMov)
            router.patch('/:id',updateMov)
            router.delete('/:id',deleteMov)

            export default router
```

in main server.js

```
            import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
            import cors from 'cors'
            import dotenv from 'dotenv'
            import mongoose from 'mongoose'
            import express from 'express'
            import movieRoutes from './routes/routes.js'
            import AdminRoutes from './routes/Admin.js'
            import trendingCardRouter from './routes/movies/Trending.js'
            import movieCardRouter from './routes/movies/movies.js'
            import WebShowRouter from './routes/movies/WebShow.js'

            const app=express()
            dotenv.config({path:'./.env'})

            app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'4gb',extended:true}))
            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'4gb',extended:true}))
            app.use(cors())

            app.use('/movies',movieRoutes)
            app.use('/admin',AdminRoutes)
            app.use('/trendCard',trendingCardRouter)
            app.use('/movieCard',movieCardRouter)
            app.use('/webshowCard',WebShowRouter)

            app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
                res.send('hello')
            })

            mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true})
                .then(()=>app.listen('5000',()=> console.log('connected')))
                .catch((err)=>console.log(err))

            mongoose.set('useFindAndModify',false)
```

and please also tell me how to send data back directly to the frontend

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for searching query in database you should send query for each databases and I recommend to use `Promise.all` for making your search faster for example use want to search in two collection , `users` and `orders` do it

```
Promise.all([
   Users.find(query),
   Orders.find(query)
])
.then(results=>{
    var users =  results[0] //// first call in Promise.all
    var orders = results[1] //// second call in Promise.all
})
.catch(errors=>{
    console.log('errors' : errors)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Aggregation` pipeline, and in first stage you can merge documents from different collections with `$unionWith` and then in second stage you can do search on some field with `$match`.

```js
Collection_1.aggregate([
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection_2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "filed_name": {
        "$regex": "search_query"
      }
    }
  }
])
```